# Minimalistic way to read TIFF image format pixels

Tags: tiff, robocup

We are participating at the RoboCup 2015 from the German Aerospace Center in October. Before the torunament we will get a 30x30 pixel sized TIFF image, representing a low-pixel heigtmap. My task is to write a fast and lightweight, **dependency free** code that reads this TIFF image an does some algorythmic stuff on it.

I googled about the TIFF image format and it seems there are some powerfull libraries, but is there a simple way of reading just the color values of the file?

I remember a format, don't know which, where I just skipped the first 30 bytes and then could read the color values in RGB. Do you have any code that could do that or an idea/explanation how I could acchieve that?

As I said, I do not need filename, imagesize data etc. I actually don't even know why they have choosen the TIFF image-format since its just a normal heightmap in greyscale, but however.

Every help is very appreciated.

Comment: If you know beforehand that the image data will not be compressed, then it will only require a small bit of code to read the pixels. If it's compressed, then you've got quite a bit more work.

Comment: It is uncompressed. How would I read the pixels then?

Comment: 1) Skip signature bytes
2) Read IFD tags until you've parsed the width, height, bpp, and image data offset
3) Read the image data
4) Done :)